# How to clear Glide library local disk cache

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I'm trying to clear Glide cache for a specific view on specific occasions only (when a user choose an image and that image is copied to the local app data folder, then displayed in an `ImageView` )

I've seen many answers recommending manipulating Glide disk cache strategy, but this will create a new image each time the activity is created, which I don't want.

My best option was to clear the whole Glide cache each time the switch button state is changed (if any better solution is available, please recommended)

I tried adding this:

```
Glide.get(getContext()).clearMemory();
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Glide.get(getContext()).clearDiskCache();
                            }
                        });
```

But the image remains cached and the old one is displayed. Any recommendations?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to use `Thread` directly, but if you must, it needs to be started https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manage to solve it using `SharedPrefrences` with a `random` number and Glide's `Signature` class

call this after new image selection

```
double random = Math.random();
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("customID",  ""+ random ).apply();
```

then when displaying the image, use this

```
Glide.with(this).load(custom_image)
.signature(new ObjectKey(themePrefs.getString("customID", "")))
.centerCrop().into(background_layout);
```

so each time a new image is selected, a new random is generated then Glide will face a different Signature (random number) and load a new image. But when the activity is resumed or restarted at any later time, the signature will remain the same, so Glide will load it from the cache.